# how to make nginx location match path both with slash and without slash?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

currently i have this location in my nginx file, it does not work with  `http://mydomain/ab/cd`.  How can i make the browser to go to the same page when user type both  `http://mydomain/ab/cd` and `http://mydomain/ab/cd/`?

```
location /ab/cd/ {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest, in terms of performance, is simply two *exact* locations:

```
location = /ab/cd {
   ...
}

location = /ab/cd/ {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`location ~* ^/ab/cd(|\/) {...}`

It is a prefix matching regex that checks if it has trailing slash or not.